# IE6 Not submitting POST Data?

Tags: php, post, internet-explorer-6

I have just tested my site on an old IE6 browser on a windows server.

The problem I have is when I submit a form, the POST data I get on the other page is empty. `Array()`.

This site has worked on IE6 on a different windows server, it has worked on my laptop and works on all other major browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE6,7,8, Safari) etc.

Its just this one machine. Is there a setting not to allow post data on IE6?

Thanks all

### HTML

```
<form method="post" action="save_settings.php">
<div class='rw'>a 
<input class='set_inp' type='text' name='a' id='a' value='' />
</div><div class='rw'>b 
<input class='set_inp' type='text' name='b' id='b' value='' />
</div><div class='rw'>c
<input class='set_inp' type='text' name='c' id='c' value='' />
</div><div class='rw'>d 
<input class='set_inp' type='text' name='d' id='d' value='' />
</div><div class='rw'>e 
<input class='set_inp' type='text' name='e' id='e' value='' />
</div><div class='rw'>f 
<input class='set_inp' type='text' name='f' id='f' value='' />
</div><div class='rw'>g 
<input class='set_inp' type='text' name='g' id='g' value='' />
</div><div class='rw'>h
<input class='set_inp' type='text' name='h' id='h' value='' />
</div><div class='rw'>i
<input class='set_inp' type='text' name='i' id='i' value='' />
</div><div class='rw'>j
<input class='set_inp' type='text' name='j' id='j' value='' />
</div>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Post the source code of your `<form>`.

Comment: We need the source, as stated above. IE6 is really picky, and will refuse to post if you have some illegal elements in the form.

Comment: I have added the form source, I have changed the id and names. Please remember, this works on other IE6 install and all other major browsers, its just this one specific machine.

Comment: does a real simple form with only one input fail as well?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference, but can you try removing the self-closing `/` at the end of each input tag? It's the only thing I can spot that's out of the ordinary to me.

Comment: @Baloo - I have tried a very simple test and it doesn't even work. @Pekka - I have done that and it still hasn't posted the data! WTF is going on with this machine??

Comment: Does sound like the answer? http://support.microsoft.com/?id=251404 - Still reading it!

Comment: As this question is neither PHP, POST or IE6 specific ... how do you want us to solve your problem?

Comment: @Mihai - Are you saying you have 3 different solutions that you can offer me but you can't decide between which of those you should give me? ;)

Comment: no I am saying that neither of your tags belong here. It's obviously something worng with your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found on here: http://support.microsoft.com/?id=251404

This setup of IE6 has a strange way of handling handshakes with the server.

In addition, enhanced security for Internet explorer was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a plugin like http://www.brothersoft.com/iehttpheaders-13615.html on your IE. That will make sure that the POST data does is not being sent to the server.

Then try an antivirus scan on your computer. I have noticed this behaviour before when there was a virus.

Remove any IE browser toolbar / extension installed.